# How do I use scanf to limit the user from entering a string no larger than the array?

Tags: c

How do I use scanf to limit the user from entering a string no larger than the array?

What i've tried so far is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
const MAXSTRING = 5;

char arr[MAXSTRING] = {};

printf("Enter a string: \n");

scanf("%*s", MAXSTRING-1, arr);

return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think this is answered well here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c

Comment: `*` means "suppress the assignment" when used with `scanf`, unlike `printf` where `*` means "use the next arg as the width/precision". So the best you can do is `"%4s"` and deal with the maintenance nightmare of keeping the `scanf` in sync with the buffer size.

Comment: `const MAXSTRING = 5;` is incorrect in modern C language.  You should specify a type.  If you want C89 compatibility, you must use a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the user enter a string terminated with a newline, it's a good idea to use `fgets` instead of `scanf`. The function `fgets` receives as a parameter the length of the buffer and won't overrun the buffer. You can check its result to figure out if truncation occured. Consult the documentation of your C language implementation for more details.

```
fgets(arr, MAXSTRING, stdin);
```

Comment: `fgets` is not semantically equivalent to the `scanf` you are replacing, but it is much easier to understand and much safer.  You should check the return value as the contents of  `arr` is indeterminate upon `EOF`.

Comment: @chqlie Indeed. That's why I state “If you want to have the user enter a string terminated with a newline, …” I really hope OP is going to read the manual before using the function (or any other function).

Answer (score 2):

Use one of:

```
1 == scanf("%4s", arr)
1 == scanf("%4[^\n]", arr)
1 == scanf("%ms", &ptr) // POSIX 2008, remember to call `free`
```

The second is useful to because `scanf`'s default behavior of separating "word"s by any whitespace is often not useful.

However, it's often better to avoid `scanf` entirely and get input a line at a time (using something like `fgets` (but beware truncation and EOF-without-EOL) or `getline` (POSIX 2008, but pretty easy to implement in terms of `fgets`)) and then use `sscanf` or simple array logic on that.

POSIX refs:

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html

Comment: `%ms` is already in POSIX! Should be portable. `getline` is part of POSIX, too, but support is spotty.

Comment: @FUZxxl hm, I guess the "posix man pages" package is still POSIX 2003, not POSIX 2008.

Comment: Sources: [fscanf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html), [getline](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html). POSIX is available for free on the internet.

Comment: @FUZxxl was aware, but the man pages are more convenient and I thought they were up-to-date.

Comment: I'm not sure why there are no man pages for POSIX.1 2008. Perhaps it's too new? As far as I know, POSIX is written roff, so it shouldn't be hard to make these man pages if the sources are available.

Comment: @FUZxxl Found an (old) bug report: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=622918

Comment: `char arr[5]; scanf("%5s", arr);` is a problem.  Try `scanf("%4s", arr);`

Comment: `scanf("%5[^\n]", arr);` puts nothing in `arr` and `arr` remains uninitialized if first `char` is `'\n'` and leaves `'\n'` in `stdin`.

Comment: @chux Well, that's what checking the return value is for. You're right about the off-by-one though.